# Hello, flowers of my caqui tree turned brown any idea why?

Tags: fruit-trees

[image]

Hello, flowers of my caqui tree turned brown any idea why?
Soil is sand

Comment: This plant is known as the persimmon tree.  Where are you growing it?  Have you watered it?  Is it dry where you are?

Comment: Yes it is a persimmon tree, I am growing it in Cairo it takes nearly 2 liters every other day in a sandy soil temperature  ranged for the last 2 months between 68    and 80f in the mornings, 55 and 68f in the evenings.